# Find The Integral Part Of The Series

Tags: summation

Find the integral part of the series.

$1/4^{1/3}$$+$$1/5^{1/3}$$+$$1/6^{1/3}$$...$$+$$1/1000000^{1/3}$.

I tried to bring it down to a summation form, hence reducing it to

$$\sum_{i=4}^n 1/i^{1/3}$$

But i still do not understand how to make it short.
I tried a lot to use telescoping strategy, but i failed. Also, the "integral part" worries me.

The cube root of $4$ must lie between $1$ and $2$. Similarly, the cube root of $5$ must lie between $1$ and $2$ again. This occurs until the $8$ number, whose cube root is $2$. But later, i found out it would be difficult for me if i use the strategy of breaking it down. Next, i do not see anything else. Please help me!

Edit: In our competitions we are not supposed to use calculus approaches, so please avoid calculus while answering this question

Comment: Just to clarify, by asking for the "integral part", are you asking for the integer part (like how the integer part of $1.5$ is $1$, or the integer part of $\pi$ is $3$), or are you asking about expressing the summation as some sort of integral (as is taught in calculus)?

Comment: Yes i am asking about the integer part